# Is there a way to overwrite Nan values in a pandas dataframe with values of the previous row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I am working with a dataframe called ´tabla_combinada´ that looks like this:

Structure of the dataframe used:

[image]

What I am attempting to do is to get rid of the Nan values in the 'End Meter' column and replace it with the value of the same column in the previous row. I tried to implement the following code:

```
counter=0
for x in tabla_combinada['End Meter']:
    if math.isnan(x):
        x = tabla_combinada['End Meter'][counter-1]
        tabla_combinada['End Meter'][counter-1] = tabla_combinada['Start Meter'][counter]       
    counter = counter + 1
```

This is not working for me, in the first place I am getting the following warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
```

But what bugs me is that I am obtaining no change in the dataframe at all. I do understand the cause of the warning and I suspect that this is not the optimal approach to solve the problem. I guess there is a proper way to do this with loc, but I couldn't find out how to tell the program to replace the Nan with the value of the previous row.
Sorry for the long question and thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify, the structure of the dataframe is in the image link below. Nevertheless, it is made of four columns: COD_TRAMO, Start Meter, End Meter and CLASE_TRAZADO. They all contain float values, except for the Nan values that I mentioned.

Comment: `tabla_combinada['End Meter'] = tabla_combinada['End_Meter'].ffill()`

Comment: in your example you're using the value from another column while in the text you say you want the previous value from the same column, which one is it?

Comment: Actually I am trying to propagate the Nan values in the 'End Meter'forward just like nferreira78 suggested and then replace the 'End Meter' value of the (n-1)th row with the 'Start Meter' value of nth row.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is this:

```
tabla_combinada['End Meter'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

This will propagate non-null values forward